# Flutter - How to catch a crash that only occurs in live build but not in debug?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that goes completely grey when in release build, but I cannot reproduce the crash in debug mode. How could I view the crash report, so I can debug the issue?

Comment: What happens when profiling the widget?

Comment: This has happened to me before & the issue was null exception. We cannot debug release applications. So, I tried to reproduce the same process & found a null exception while debugging. Try creating release build once again & test if the issue persists.

Comment: Try `runZoned` to catch unhandled exceptions. This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/catcher#toast-handler) does the same thing.